# Data Execution Prevention suddenly prevents Console2 from running

Tags: windows, cygwin, dep

Not sure what happened but when I got to work today, Console2 stopped working. Every time I try opening it Windows XP (SP2) complains:

[error dialogs](http://yfrog.com/3uerrormvj) (can't post images yet)

I tried messing with DEP preferences in System->Performance, adding cmd.exe and console2.exe but to no avail. My first thought was maybe a Windows Update messed things up, but I checked for updates that were installed lately and the last one was a month ago.

What's even stranger is that initially only I had this problem, then my coworker started seeing strange errors as well and when he restarted his computer, he was getting the same errors as I did.

Another thing that might or might not be related, my Cygwin started working **really** slow for no apparent reason, start up time, simple commands like echo, ls, all take around 30 seconds to return.

Comment: Virus? Make sure to check for that first.

Comment: Probably a worm (virus that spreads itself). Follow the directions at http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware to try and clean it up.

Comment: I'll check those out but we're inside a pretty secure network

Answer (score 0):

Disable the DEP in your BIOS.

We were having issues with HP DEP feature. Some of our software were acting weird before we disabled it.

Comment: This might fix your issue. Give it a try! We were having problems in the office to get into our Intranet when DEP was enabled. As soon as disabled, everything worked fine! Just a random example...